# Node to a word of the content of a matrix cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to draw various things relatively to some parts of matrix rows, but for `\node (a) {this}; is one row\\` for example of a row in a matrix, only the part between the curved brackets are printed in the output pdf.
Here is one example end result of what I try to achieve, which I did in inkscape.

[image]

Here is the mwe without anything related to the drawing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\tikzset{
  texttable/.style={row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={anchor=center,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt,
        text width=#1,text depth=.5ex,text height=10pt, font=\large}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix at (0,0) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    matrix anchor=north west,
    texttable={6cm}, align=right,row 1/.style={align=left},row 2/.style={align=right}] (tb1)
    {
    ceci est une pomme\\
%    \node (a) {ceci}; est une pomme\\  %%this outputs only "ceci"
    this is an apple\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `subnodes` from `tikzmark` library.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=30mm,hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc, decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
  texttable/.style={row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={anchor=center,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=3pt,
        text width=#1,text depth=.5ex,text height=10pt, font=\large}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \matrix at (0,0) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    matrix anchor=north west,
    texttable={6cm}, align=right,row 1/.style={align=left},row 2/.style={align=right}] (tb1)
    {
    \subnode{ceci}{ceci} est une pomme\\
    \subnode{this}{this} is an apple\\
    };
    \node (approx) at (ceci|-this) {$\approx$};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, mirror}] (ceci.south west)--(ceci.south east);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace, mirror}] (this.south west)--(this.south east);
    \draw (approx.south)--++(-90:3mm)-|([yshift=-2mm]this.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you put "approx" above the horizontal line in the middle, or by breaking the line over ~4mm long and put it there?

Comment: @user1850133 Zarko already showed you how to do it. Is it enough?

Comment: yes it is enough

Answer (score 4):

To long for the comment ...

a very small stylistic variation of nice @Ignasi answer (+1):

- styles of picture elements are defined as options of `tikzpicture`
- simpler way to change matrix width
- calligraphic braces below subnodes
- `\approx` simbol is insert as label of line between subnodes

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                matrix,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
BC/.style = {decorate,
             decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt, raise=0pt},
             thick,
             pen colour=black}, 
 sn/.style = {inner xsep=0pt},
lbl/.style = {sn, pos=0.6, fill=white},
                        ] 
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes = {text width=60mm,
                      text depth=.5ex, text height=3ex, font=\large,
                      inner ysep=1pt, anchor=center},
             row 1/.style={align=left},
             row 2/.style={align=right},
            ]
{
\subnode[sn]{a}{ceci} est une pomme \\
\subnode[sn]{b}{this} is an apple   \\
};
\draw[BC]   (a.south east) -- (a.south west);
\draw[BC]   (b.south east) -- (b.south west);
\draw[shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt]
            (a) -- node[lbl] {$\approx$} ++ (0,-1.2) -| (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

For considering of the OP comment, the following changes in my MWE had to be done:

- definition for `lbl` for label on arrows between sub-nodes should be changed to  `lbl/.style = {pos=#1, fill=white},`
- arrow between sub-nodes should be changed to

```
\draw[shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt]
            (a) -- ++ (0,-1.2) -| node[lbl=0.25] {$\approx$} (b);
```

After those changes compilation of given MWE produce:

[image]

Comment: `subnode` *and* `calligraphy`!  What's not to like?

Comment: Dear @AndrewStacey, I admire and often use both packages. Thank you very much for them!

Comment: can you put "approx" on the horizontal portion of the line linking the two accolades?

Comment: @user1850133, yes, by moving it to second pat of line between sub nodes. Will be corrected ASAP.

Comment: @user1850133, see addendum to answer. Is now what you like to have.